# Why use à and not aux and de not des in « à tous les coins de rue » ?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, prépositions

I recently learnt the expression

> à tous les coins de rue

When using SRS to learn this phrase, my mind instinctively puts it as ***aux** tous les coins de rue* as there is plural that follows.

I am assuming that because the preposition is followed by *tous* which is not a noun, we use *à* here. Is that right? Is this the general rule?

In addition, my mind is also having a hard time understanding why it is *de rue*. I am assuming it is because you should treat *coin de rue* as a singular unit and the plural is simply *coins de rue* as it is a compound noun.

Answer (score 2):

*Aux* replaces *à les*. Here we have *à **tous** les* so we cannot use *aux*.
Without the *tous* we would indeed say *aux coins de rue*.

For your second question, *de rue* is a noun complement and whether or not it takes the plural mark depends on the meaning on the sentence. Here, *coin de rue* is indeed to be seen as a unit (one may argue that there are intersections but in this sentence, one corner belongs to one street) and *rue* stays singular.
More information and examples can be found here:
http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2914